# Store ansible output to variable

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

I want to use Ansible that would get information about an AWS Ec2 instance. I am really looking for it's Instance-ID. I am going to use this to loop through a template. But I can't seem to get the instance-ID. Here is what I have so far:

```
---
- name: Including Variables
  include_vars:
    file: Linux.yml

- name: Gathering EC2 Facts
  ec2_remote_facts:
    aws_access_key: "{{ access_key }}"
    aws_secret_key: "{{ secret_key }}"
    region: us-east-1
    filters:
        "tag:Name": "{{ ansible_hostname }}"
  register: instanceId
- debug: var=instanceId.instances.id
```

I know this is incorrect as when I run this i get:

> "instanceId.instances.id": "VARIABLE IS NOT DEFINED!"

Can someone tell me of a way to return the instanceId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do something for the first time, do it gradually... To understand what's inside. Like:

```
- debug: var=instanceId
# to see raw result and find out that `instances` is there

- debug: var=instanceId.instances
# to see what `instanses` is, and to see it is a list

- debug: var=instanceId.instances[0]
# to see the first element of the list and see it's properties

- debug: var=instanceId.instances[0].id
# to see instance ID
```

Comment: Got it. Thanks for that -- I was doing that up until i got instancesId.instances but wasn't exactly sure how to pull the instance Ids at that point but this works pretty well :-)